# C# 4.x Antlr Runtime

Tags: antlr4

I was looking for the `C# Runtime` for `Antlr 4`, and there is direct download a v4 runtime on the [www.antlr.org](http://www.antlr.org) website.

After reading the documentation it says to use `NuGet` to get the `Antlr4 Runtime`.

However on searching `NuGet` for `Antlr`, `Antlr4`, `Antlr 4`, There are no `Antlr4` runtimes there atm. There is a package for `StringTemplate4` when you search for `Antlr4`, but no direct `Antlr4` Runtime.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I believe the VS Extension is only available in VS2010 and below.

Comment: I have tried searching in both VS2012 & VS2013

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for installing the C# target of ANTLR 4 can be found in the readme.md file located at the bottom of the following page, including instructions for installing the NuGet package(s):

https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your filter options in the Nuget Package Manager from "Stable Only" to "Include Prerelease"

Answer (score 0):

From my own attempts, I have found that the ANTLR extension for Visual Studio is only available in VS2010 and below.